# How do i draw London Bus Routes?

Tags: openstreetmap, network-analyst, routing, network, arcgis-10.6

I want to draw all London bus routes. I have the associated bus stop locations and sequences. Is there a quick way to draw the routes?

My end product would be a shapefile or layer file / table with all the routes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Python and shapely/Geopandas to make a Linestring to join bus-stop A coordinates to bus-stop B coordinates, rather than them existing as just points. Haven't tested the below but general idea:

```
import geopandas as gp
import pandas as pd
import shapely

#read in csv for one bus route, and sort by a 
#sequence value to get the bus stops in order
df = pd.read_csv('csv with lat, lon, sequence.csv')
df = df.sort_by('sequence')

#create a Point feature for the current bus stop
df['point'] = df.apply(lambda x: shapely.geometry.Point(x['lon'], x['lat']), axis=1)

#create another column to contain the next bus stop Point in the sequence
df['point_1'] = df.point.shift(-1)

#create another column which draws a line between the two
df['line'] = df.apply(lambda x: shapely.geometry.LineString((x['point'], x['point_1'])), axis=1)

#create a geodataframe and establish crs and set the geometries with the created line
gf = gp.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='line')
gf.crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}

#save to shapefile
gf = gf.drop(['point', 'point_1'], axis=1)
gf.to_file('shapefile', driver='ESRI Shapefile')
```

Note this wont get you the actual route, just the straight lines between bus stops..it would be a much more difficult job to take into account the actual path of the roads. You may need to a more granular data set from here: https://api.tfl.gov.uk/ ie track the actual buses.

EDIT: I think that https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro is probably the way to go here actually. You can query the API for start and end points, set mode of transport and it will return an encoded polyline, there will then probably be a way of translating this into a "normal" LineString that can be saved into a shapefile.